# Plugin Phonegap Power Management Ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I tried to install this plugin to iOS now with cordova 2.7. I use Xcode

I put in the config.xml

```
<plugin name="PowerManagement" value="PowerManagement" />
```

In the folder plugins : PowerManagement.h and PowerManagement.m files

and in my html :

```
  cordova.require('cordova/plugin/powermanagement').acquire(
                function() { alert( 'MARCHE' ); },
                function() { alert( 'oh no!' ); }
```

I haven't any alert in my iPhone, I don't know why.

I have this error :CDVPlugin class PowerManagement (pluginName: PowerManagement) does not exist. 2013-07-03 14:36:34.619 ERROR: Plugin 'PowerManagement' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml. 2013-07-03 14:36:34.625 -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 116] FAILED pluginJSON = [ "PowerManagement1817140935", "PowerManagement", "release", [ ] ]

Comment: did you include the powermanagement.js and linked it in your index.html?

Comment: yes     <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/vendor/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
 <script src="js/powermanagement.js"></script>

Comment: The plugin might be outdated

Answer (score 3):

The version of the plugin on [github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PowerManagement) needs updating for recent versions of Phonegap. I needed to use it, so I updated it. My XCode test project containing the updated plugin  can be downloaded [from here](http://ge.tt/3cez0Rl/v/0). Source code for the updated plugin:

**PowerManagement.h**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011-2012 Wolfgang Koller
 *
 * This file is part of GOFG Sports Computer - http://www.gofg.at/.
 *
 * GOFG Sports Computer is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * GOFG Sports Computer is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with GOFG Sports Computer.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

/**
 * Cordova (iOS) plugin for accessing the power-management functions of the device
 */

#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
#import <CORDOVA/CDVPlugin.h>
#else
#import "CORDOVA/CDVPlugin.h"
#endif

/**
 * Interface which does the actual handling
 */
@interface PowerManagement :CDVPlugin {
}
/**
 * Sets the idleTimerDisable property to true so that the idle timeout is disabled
 */
- (void) acquire:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

/**
 * Sets the idleTimerDisable property to false so that the idle timeout is enabled
 */
- (void) release:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

**PowerManagement.m**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011-2012 Wolfgang Koller
 * 
 * This file is part of GOFG Sports Computer - http://www.gofg.at/.
 * 
 * GOFG Sports Computer is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * GOFG Sports Computer is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with GOFG Sports Computer.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

/**
 * Cordova (iOS) plugin for accessing the power-management functions of the device
 */
#import "PowerManagement.h"

/**
 * Actual implementation of the interface
 */
@implementation PowerManagement
- (void) acquire:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

    // Acquire a reference to the local UIApplication singleton
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    if( ![app isIdleTimerDisabled] ) {
        [app setIdleTimerDisabled:true];

        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    }
    else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION messageAsString:@"IdleTimer already disabled"];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}


- (void) release:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
{    
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

    // Acquire a reference to the local UIApplication singleton
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    if( [app isIdleTimerDisabled] ) {
        [app setIdleTimerDisabled:false];

        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    }
    else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION messageAsString:@"IdleTimer not disabled"];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
@end
```

**powermanagement.js**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011-2012 Wolfgang Koller
 * 
 * This file is part of GOFG Sports Computer - http://www.gofg.at/.
 * 
 * GOFG Sports Computer is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * GOFG Sports Computer is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with GOFG Sports Computer.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

cordova.define("cordova/plugin/powermanagement", function(require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require('cordova/exec');

    var PowerManagement = function() {};

    /**
     * Acquire a new wake-lock (keep device awake)
     * 
     * @param successCallback function to be called when the wake-lock was acquired successfully
     * @param errorCallback function to be called when there was a problem with acquiring the wake-lock
     */
    PowerManagement.prototype.acquire = function(successCallback,failureCallback) {
        exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'PowerManagement', 'acquire', []);
    }

    /**
     * Release the wake-lock
     * 
     * @param successCallback function to be called when the wake-lock was released successfully
     * @param errorCallback function to be called when there was a problem while releasing the wake-lock
     */
    PowerManagement.prototype.release = function(successCallback,failureCallback) {
        exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'PowerManagement', 'release', []);
    }

    var powermanagement = new PowerManagement();
    module.exports = powermanagement;
});
```