# How to keep the screen on an iPhone with Phonegap 2.7

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I do an ios application (ios6) with cordova 2.7 which use the GPS and I need that the screen of the Iphone is always on. I want to avoid the phone from sleep.

I tried to install this plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PowerManagement but apparently it is too old.

How do that?

Comment: @JamieStarke had a great answer, did it work for you?

Answer (score 8):

If you're willing to get your hands dirty, this can be quite easy to fix, by making a Cordova Plugin.

If you haven't made a Cordova plugin, it is definitely a skill that you should master, as not all functionality is available through PhoneGap plugins yet, and it can frequently be quite easy to make it work. The full details are available in the [PhoneGap Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide).

For this, your JavaScript side of the plugin would be something like

```
cordova.exec(function(winParam) {}, function(error) {}, "myPlugin", "preventSleep", []);
```

In this case, your PhoneGap would look for a method named `preventSleep` in the `myPlugin` class.

Next, your `preventSleep` method would look something like

```
- (void)preventSleep:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

Now you could make a corresponding method like `allowSleep` that set `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an up-to-date plugin also supported by PhoneGap Build: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I've updated this plugin for more recent versions of Phonegap (2.5 to 2.9) - you can find the source code and my XCode test project in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448783/plugin-phonegap-power-management-ios-6/17581972#17581972).

Are you sure you want to keep the screen on all the time? Apple are fairly strict on when this is allowed and may reject your app if it's not for a good reason. If you just need to allow you app to keep running and receive position updates in the background, this can be done without a plugin by adding the following to your project .plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
  <string>location</string>
</array>
```

Or in XCode, open the .plist and add the key "Required Background Modes" and value "App registers for location updates"

Comment: Works fine for me - I've developed an iOS app using this method and Apple approved it for sale. It's a guided walk app and on field testing it in the real world on an iPhone 4S, I've had the app running in the background for over an hour - the log files show that it was consistently receiving position updates during that entire time. I assume you're using watchPosition() to register a watcher for iOS to call on each update?

Comment: No I use getcurrent Position I can't do otherwise :s. So what can I do   to do that?

Comment: getCurrentPosition() will only ask iOS for one position whereas watchPosition() will set up a watcher that iOS passes a position to every time it receives an update. It will execute the onSuccess JS method even while the app is in the background. If you want iOS to continue to update the position while in the background, you must use [watchPosition](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition). Other JS, such as setTimeout, will not continue to work in the background. [See here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/cnh9KjA-d_)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've already seen this but it looks like there's a plugin available for iOS on phonegap build, apparently an android version is coming out soon.

[Link here](https://github.com/simplec-dev/powermanagement/blob/a55652d0a622d7dd3629272c6428383d88f18531/README.md)