# How to keep mobile screen on

Tags: meteor, meteor-cordova

I'm working on a Meteor Application which runs for long times and I'm looking for a way to keep the screen on when there's no user activity (while the app is running of course).

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate, have a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529247/in-html5-how-can-i-keep-an-android-device-s-screen-on

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that other question. The other question was asking about HTML, not phonegap/cordova.

Comment: The other topic does answer the question, kinda.. You need Java to do keep a device's screen active (needs os interface). So find yourself a cordova plugin that does this and add it in to your build. The process of implementing the plugin I don't know.

Comment: This question is about a different platform. a solution for meteor is required which works on all devices (hopefully)

Comment: Maybe this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451553/how-to-keep-the-screen-on-an-iphone-with-phonegap-2-7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I read the [documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration) correctly, and I may not, because I've never used this before, then you can add the [insomnia plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/842) to your cordova/phonegap build like this:

```
$ meteor add cordova:nl.x-services.plugins.insomnia@https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin/tarball/47ba15a4ad791eb4d5a0643cdb7ef69f73109e15
```

And then use:

```
window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()
```

and

```
window.plugins.insomnia.allowSleepAgain()
```

---

**Update for [Meteor 1.2](https://quip.com/RXFlAk9Rc2xI):**

> **Install plugins from a Git URL:** Meteor no longer supports installing Cordova plugins from tarball URLs, but does support Git
>   URLs with a SHA reference (like
>   https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#c452f1a67f41cb1165c92555f0e721fbb07329cc).
>   Existing GitHub tarball URLs are converted automatically.

This means that you now need to use:

```
$ meteor add cordova:nl.x-services.plugins.insomnia@https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin#47ba15a4ad791eb4d5a0643cdb7ef69f73109e15
```

**Update 2**

As user3819370 points out, the plugin is now in the registry being used by meteor, so you can simply install it like this:

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-insomnia@4.0.1
```

Comment: This is exactly how it works. I made a small sample project, check it out on GitHub: https://github.com/yauh/sleepwalker

Comment: Hi, 
didn't yet get it to work with my app on Nexus 5...
I'll DL the example Stephan did and see if I can figure it out.
Keep you posted

Comment: Got it to work! I was firing it on the wrong place...
Thanks!!

Comment: This does not work anymore. Upon adding the package, i get the following error:

=> Errors while initializing project:         
                                              
While reading project metadata:
/Users/lucanaterop/Desktop/freedive/.meteor/packages: Version string must look like semver (eg
'1.2.3'), not
'https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin/tarball/89374cb52b049fe4e9836e4b702591f35c875805'.

Comment: Nothing of the above worked for me. What does it is simply `meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-insomnia@4.0.1`

Comment: A few hints to those trying to test this: - `window.plugins.insomnia` looks to JS as an empty object, but does contain the function `keepAwake`; to test if it's working, simply pass a `successCallback` and `errorCallback` as argument to `keepAwake` to see if it worked. - It's hard to test this on iPhone, since Xcode already prevents sleep while running your test app on the iPhone on cable. I'm making a build for android to test without cable.